# How to respawn a script in RHEL/Centos6 when /etc/inittab has been deprecated?

Tags: linux, centos, upstart, init, inittab

I have a custom init script and I want that script to be respawned if in case the process dies.

In RHEL/Centos 6 /etc/inittab is deprecated. So how should I ensure the process will be respawned?

Answer (score 3):

On RHEL 6 to respawn a script, go to /etc/init and create a file

```
cd /etc/init
vi scriptFileName.conf
```

And add this content

```
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[12345]
stop on runlevel [!12345]
respawn
exec /you/respawned/script.sh -your -parameters
```

Save file and then launch this command (without .conf of file)

```
start scriptFileName
```

Thats all!

Comment: seems like ubuntu `upstart` service manager

Answer (score 0):

I normally use supervisord.

http://supervisord.org/

clean and simple.

Here's a nice example:

```
[program:vmstats]
; this assumes that there's a symlink from vmstats->vmstats-VERSION
command=/apps/vmstats/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/apps/vmstats/log4j.properties -jar /apps/vmstats/vmstats-2.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/apps/vmstats/                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true       ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
startsecs=3                  ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
user=vmstats                  ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/var/log/vmstats/vmstats-stdout.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/var/log/vmstats/vmstats-stderr.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
```

you can see it here: 
https://github.com/Nordstrom/vmstats/blob/master/supervisord/vmstats.conf

Comment: Thanks a lot John for quick help. That looks great. But I was looking for some functionality which is native to linux. Something which is alternative to 'inittab'. Any idea about that?

Comment: you can use /etc/init (which is different then /etc/init.d ) and use respawn in the init file , you can see a good example here: http://grokbase.com/t/centos/centos/11a4n4x2gt/migrating-centos-5-6-where-to-put-etc-inittab-respawn-scripts

Comment: @Shashank systemd will handle this in RHEL 7, but you didn't say you were using that.